# Split Map to multiple Maps

Tags: scala

I need to process a diff between two (huge) `Map`s. To parallelize the task, I would like to split these 2 `Map`s by Key hash value and create smaller `Map`s (by range of hash value).

How would I archieve that in (idiomatic) Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough sketch to get you started with the Scala syntax:

```
// create two (slightly different) maps, print them as table side by side
val rnd = new util.Random
val originalMap1 = (0 to 10).map(i => (i, i * i)).toMap
val originalMap2 = (0 to 10).map(i => (i, i * i + rnd.nextInt(2))).toMap
for (i <- 0 to 10) {
  val a = originalMap1(i)
  val b = originalMap2(i)
  val marker = if (a == b) "" else " <-"
  println(s"$i: $a $b $marker")
}

//subdivide into smaller maps
val numSubmaps = 5
val submaps1 = originalMap1.groupBy(_._1.hashCode % numSubmaps)
val submaps2 = originalMap2.groupBy(_._1.hashCode % numSubmaps)

// compare each corresponding pair of maps separately, merge diffs
val diffs = (for (s <- 0 until numSubmaps) yield {
  val m1 = submaps1(s)
  val m2 = submaps2(s)
  for { 
    k <- m1.keys
    a = m1(k)
    b = m2(k)
    if a != b
  } yield (k, (a, b))
}).reduce(_ ++ _)

println(diffs.toList.sortBy(_._1))
```

Input:

```
0: 0 1  <-
1: 1 2  <-
2: 4 4 
3: 9 9 
4: 16 16 
5: 25 26  <-
6: 36 36 
7: 49 49 
8: 64 65  <-
9: 81 82  <-
10: 100 101  <-
```

Output:

```
List((0,(0,1)), (1,(1,2)), (5,(25,26)), (8,(64,65)), (9,(81,82)), (10,(100,101)))
```